# Add html buttons and selects to Highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I want to add custom buttons to the title area of a Highcharts chart.  My goal is to make the buttons and such part of the chart, not a div above or below it.  I have this working for the most part, but when adding a select box to the title area and then clicking to open it, nothing happens.

```
$(function() {
  $('#container2').highcharts({
    chart: {
      events: {
        load: function() {
          loadChartButtons();
        }
      }
    },
    title: {
      text: 'loading',
      align: 'right',
      x: -50,
      useHTML: true
    },
    xAxis: {
      categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun']
    },
    series: [{
      data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0]
    }],

  });
});


function loadChartButtons() {
  var element1 = '<button id="testbtn" class="btn btn-primary">Test</button>';
  var element2 = '<select id="testselect"><option>test1</option><option>test2</option><option selected>test3</option></select>';
  $('#container2 span.highcharts-title').html(element1 + ' ' + element2);
}
```

Here's a fiddle of what I have so far: http://jsfiddle.net/quyx7L0m/

Comment: Putting select inside a span seems to cause the probleme, try placing it before/after the container ?

 $('#container2').before(element1 + ' ' + element2);

Comment: The span is dynamically created via Highcharts, nothing I can do about that.  For kicks, in Chrome I edited the html to change the span to div and had the same result, the select box would not open.  To restate, my goal is to add the html elements inside the highcharts chart, not outside of it as suggested.

There must be a programmatic reason why the select element won't open while inside the chart.  My guess is that there's some sort of preventDefault issue that I can't see.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jw9s7m6f/

Answer (score 1):

Highcharts captures all events from the chart container. You can create a wrap, which will create an exception for `select` element.

```
Highcharts.wrap(Highcharts.Pointer.prototype, 'onContainerMouseDown', function(proceed, e) {

    var popupClass = e.target && e.target.className;

    // elements is not in popup
    if (!(Highcharts.isString(popupClass) &&
            popupClass.indexOf('highcharts-title-select') >= 0)) {

        proceed.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
    }
});
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/60x45wsg/

Comment: Excellent!!  Thanks for actually reading my request and responding.